# MVC4 Localization with DisplayName in Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, localization

I have a MVC4 website with different resourcefiles linked to it and the localization works fine.

But what I want to do is get the values from a database, instead of dealing with resx files.

I extended the "DisplayNameAttribute" class to take a key (integer) and a CultureInfo object and use them to retrieve the values from the database.

The thing I want from the CultureInfo is its string representation (e.g. "en-US" or "fr-FR").

My problem is that I can pass the integer to the constructor of the extended class, but not the CultureInfo.

Code sample of the extended attribute :

```
public class LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
{
    private int ResourceKey { get; set; }
    private CultureInfo Culture { get; set; }

    public LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute(int resourceKey, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ResourceKey = resourceKey;
        Culture = culture;
    }

    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            string displayName = "Get from database.. TEST";
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayName) ? string.Format("[[{0}]]", ResourceKey) : displayName;
        }
    }

}
```

What I would like to do:

```
[LocalizedDisplayName(1, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture))]  
public string userName  { get; set; } //The full name of the user
```

Or even better:

```
private CultureInfo culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;

[LocalizedDisplayName(1, culture))]  
public string userName  { get; set; } //The full name of the user
```

My question is, how do I do this?

Comment: You can't put `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` as an argument for you attribute because it's not a compile time value. Why don't you use immediatly `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` where you need it?

Comment: Can't you just get the CultureInfo in DisplayName property or constructor?

Comment: As obvious as this solution is, I didn't think this would work. But actually it does and also makes the model code cleaner. Thanks! If you could submit this as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question was provided by Ksven first and Tomi Lammi second in the comments:

As Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture is not a compile time value, it can not be provided as an argument for the LocalizedDisplayName attribute. So the solution is to use it in the attribute method instead of providing it as an argument:

```
public override string DisplayName
{
   get
   {
        var culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture; 
        var displayName = db.sp_getValueFromDatabase(id, culture.Name).firstOrDefault();
   }
}
```

As I can not accept comments as an accepted answer, I have made my own answer. If one of the above commenters could post their solution as an answer, I will make their answer the accepted one.